# ERROR: Cannot uninstall requests 2.25.1, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by rpm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, python-requests

While I'm installing my dependency in my ec2 machine I'm getting this error.

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall requests 2.25.1, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by rpm.
> I have checked the dependency. I haven't found any conflicts in my local machine.
> Here are the my requirements.txt

```
azure-cognitiveservices-speech==1.28.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
bs4==0.0.1
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
decorator==4.4.2
google-api-core==2.11.0
google-api-python-client==2.86.0
google-auth==2.18.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.0
httplib2==0.22.0
idna==3.4
imageio==2.28.1
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.8
jellyfish==0.11.2
joblib==1.2.0
moviepy==1.0.3
mutagen==1.46.0
networkx==3.1
nltk==3.8.1
numpy==1.24.3
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
Pillow==9.5.0
proglog==0.1.10
protobuf==4.23.0
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pydub==0.25.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
rake-nltk==1.0.6
regex==2023.5.5
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rsa==4.9
segtok==1.5.11
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.4.1
tabulate==0.9.0
tqdm==4.65.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.15
yake==0.4.8
```

I tried to uninstall the package by running this command
`sudo rpm -e requests-2.25.1`
Still problem is not resolved.
I have removed the package from the requirements.txt still problem doesn't solve.
I would like to know why this error is getting and how can I fix it

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because an older version of the "requests" module was installed using the OS package manager and PIP is not able to upgrade it. To fix this issue the RPM package needs to be removed.

```
sudo yum remove python3-requests
```

This can incorporated into the playbook using a pre_task which would run before the role, for example:
pre_tasks:

```
- name: Remove python3-requests
  ansible.builtin.package:
    name: python3-requests
    state: absent
```

Credit: https://docs.slingnode.com/slingnode.ethereum/known-issues

Answer (score 2):

I have also got the same issue while practicing Ansible lab from "Techworld with Nana" boot camp, Below are steps that resolved my issue:

My machine Platform: Amazon Linux (Inferred)

**Did docker python module installation as ec2-user**, instead of mixing it with other rpm installations as the root user

```
- name: Install docker python module
  hosts: aws
  become: yes
  become_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
    - name: Install docker python module #This is dependency with ansible docker_image module
      pip:
        name: docker
```

Full Ansible playbook in case if you are interested

```
---
- name: Install python3,docker and docker-compose
  hosts: aws
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Make sure python3 and docker are installed
      vars: 
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python
      dnf:  #yum module as ofnow supports only python2 interpreter
        name: 
          - python3
          - docker
          - python3-pip
        update_cache: yes
        state: present
    - name: Install docker-compose
      get_url: 
        url: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-Linux-{{lookup('pipe', 'uname -m')}} #using "lookup" from jinja template to interpret commands inside url
        dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
        mode: +x
    - name: Ensure docker is running
      systemd:
        name: docker
        state: started


- name: Add user to docker group
  hosts: aws
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Add ec2-user to docker group
      user:
        name: ec2-user
        groups: docker
        append: yes
    - name: Reconnect to server session
      meta: reset_connection  #To reset connection immediate after above task

- name: Install docker python module
  hosts: aws
  become: yes
  become_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
    - name: Install docker python module #This is dependency with ansible docker_image module
      pip:
        name: docker

- name: Test docker pull
  hosts: aws
  tasks:
    - name: pull redis
      # command: docker pull redis
      docker_image:
        name: redis
        source: pull
```